# File to list, split by newlines (python 3.5.0)

Tags: python

How can I convert a fasta file in python to a list, split by two newlines?

So, this is how the file looks like:

```
Subject1...
Subject1...
Subject1...
[Enter]
[Enter]
Subject2...
Subject2...
Subject2...
```

I need something like this, in a list:

```
[Subject1
Subject1
Subject1,
Subject2
Subject2
Subject2]
```

So, every few lines of one 'subject' should be one item together, so that I can remove or print all lines of one specific subject.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some sort of splitting character(s) to mark when subject ends?

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

Read the file into memory:

```
text = myfile.read()
```

[Split the text](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
subjects = text.split("\n\n")
```

A quick demo:

```
In [2]: text = """Subject1...
   ...: Subject1...
   ...: Subject1...
   ...:
   ...: Subject2...
   ...: Subject2...
   ...: Subject2...
   ...:
   ...: Subject3...
   ...: Subject3...
   ...: Subject3..."""

In [3]: text.split("\n\n")
Out[3]:
['Subject1...\nSubject1...\nSubject1...',
 'Subject2...\nSubject2...\nSubject2...',
 'Subject3...\nSubject3...\nSubject3...']
```